# How to save Mongodb embedded array in Yii2

Tags: mongodb, yii2

I am new in Mongodb and YII2. I just want to know how can I save embedded array using YII2 framework?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [yii2-mongodb component readme](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/blob/master/docs/guide/usage-embedded-documents.md) "This extension does not provide any special way to work with embedded documents (sub-documents) at the moment."

So, you may look at [Doctrine MongoDB ODM](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/) and adopt it into yii2 framework as well as it done in many other frameworks.
Doctrine ODM has most [useful features](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/embedded-mapping.html) to manage your embedded data among other PHP MongoDB ODMs.